# DropIt how to copy pdf files from folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, copy, backup, directory

I installed the **DropIt** product to copy PDF files from the selected folder and its subfolders.

I defined association :

1. rule: **;*.pdf which means any subfolder and just PDF files).
2. action: copy
3. destination folder : c:\mybackup\%SubDir%\

I drag and drop a selected folder and drop it into DropIt's icon.

Actually no file matches

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use only `*.pdf` and I assume it will already check all subfolder and process .pdf files.